# How to access a pdf file from iOS Titanium module which is under Titanium mobile project resource folder?

Tags: ios, path, titanium

I'm creating a titanium mobile application which contains iOS module for **PDF** editing. I'm having a pdf file in titanium project(**Titanium Studio**) resource directory. How to access the **PDF** file from iOS Module?

I got the file path using `Titanium.Filesystem.getResourcesDirectory()+'filename.pdf';`

And pass the path to iOS module as method parameter.

How to get the file in iOS Module??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its in the Resources directory then just pass the name to the module, since this means the PDF is in the main application assets bundle, use this code to get a path to it:

```
// The application assets can be accessed by building a path from the mainBundle of the application.
NSString *filePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.pdf"];
```

[Heres a reference to this inside the moddevguide for iOS from Titanium.](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/blob/master/moddevguide/mobile/ios/Classes/TiModdevguideModule.m)

As an addendum If you find yourself trying to pass a full path around to a module in iOS, you need to [resolve the native path](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem.File-method-resolve) by doing this:

```
var file = Titanium.Filesystem.getResourcesDirectory()+'filename.pdf';
var actualPathToPassToModule = file.resolve();
```

Comment: I think you answered every way to deal with a file except for the way he asked for. :) Still useful info, though.

Comment: Yep, I missed that one. Maybe it will help someone. I would edit but you've got a good answer!

Comment: But to get file.resolve() we need to use -> var file  = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.getResourcesDirectory() + 'document.pdf');

Answer (score 2):

You can use TiUtils's method "toUrl:proxy:". The example from the docs is as follows, but it applies to an arg that you take in from JS land too (just substitute the "path" string for your own):

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"modules/%@/foo.png",[self moduleId]];
NSURL *url = [TiUtils toURL:path proxy:self];
UIImage *image = [TiUtils image:url proxy:self];
```

- http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/iOS_Module_Development_Guide-section-29004946_iOSModuleDevelopmentGuide-ReturningFiles

"self" can be your module, because TiModules are proxies themselves (in other words, leaving it as self is probably fine for you).

Want a more full example? Look at the AirPrint module I wrote a while ago. The "print:(id)args" method takes in a { url: "whatever.pdf" }, turns it in to a URL, and does something interesting with it on the UI thread.

```
- (void)print:(id)args
{
    ENSURE_UI_THREAD(print,args);
    ENSURE_SINGLE_ARG(args,NSDictionary);

    NSURL* url = [TiUtils toURL:[args objectForKey:@"url"] proxy:self];
    if (url==nil) {
        NSLog(@"[ERROR] Print called without passing in a url property!");
        return;
    }
```

- https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/blob/master/airprint/mobile/ios/Classes/TiAirprintModule.m

Comment: +1 didn't know about the `[TiUtils toURL:arg]` or the TiModule selfing . Very nice!